# How to override default stable Nvidia driver

Tags: nixos

I'm trying to override the stable nvidia package from my `configuration.nix` from nvidia driver `410` to `390`, however, it doesn't seem to work using the override config below.

I am enabling the driver using the `services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia" ]` option and am subscribed to the `unstable` channel.

configuration.nix:

```
  nixpkgs.config = {
    allowUnfree = true;

    packageOverrides = super: let self = super.pkgs; in
    {
        linuxPackages = super.linuxPackages_latest.extend (self: super: {
          nvidiaPackages = super.nvidiaPackages // {
            stable = super.nvidiaPackages.stable_390;
          };
        });
    };
  };
```

I also tried changing from `super` to `self` in the following line:

`stable = super.nvidiaPackages.stable_390;`

But this doesn't have any affect either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've been able to figure out, you'll need to override both the linux packages and `nvidia_x11` in the core package set. If I didn't, I encountered a silent fallback to the default nvidia drivers.

The following is an example that is less fine-grained than your attempt. My thinking was that there was a possibility of a mismatch between kernel dependencies used to build and loaded at runtime, so I instead swapped out the entire linuxPackage set.

At present (01/10/2019), nvidia 410.7x is broken (see [Issue 53708](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/53708)). So I've pinned my configuration to the last commit with nvidia 410.6x. For more information on pinning nixpkgs, see [the wiki page](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ/Pinning_Nixpkgs). You can still pin against master and add an `unstable` namespace to your package set without interfering with the kernel.

```
{ config, pkgs, nixpkgs, ... }:

let
  # get the last working revision with nvidia 410.x
  nixos-unstable-pinned = import (builtins.fetchTarball {
    name = "nixos-unstable_nvidia-410-66_2018-11-03";
    url = https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/archive/bf084e0ed7a625b50b1b0f42b98358dfa23326ee.tar.gz;
    sha256 = "0w05cw9s2pa07vqy21ack7g7983ig67lhwkdn24bzah3z49c2d8k";
  }) { };

  # We'll use this twice
  pinnedKernelPackages = nixos-unstable-pinned.linuxPackages_latest;

in

{
  # allow nvidia drivers to be loaded 
  nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;

  nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    # swap out all of the linux packages
    linuxPackages_latest = pinnedKernelPackages;

    # make sure x11 will use the correct package as well
    nvidia_x11 = nixos-unstable-pinned.nvidia_x11;
  };

  # line up your kernel packages at boot
  boot.kernelPackages = pinnedKernelPackages;
}
```

Hope this helps!